# Can not use the index in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to read a excel file to a dataframe and reindex in the str  time and used loc to slice a part of it , but in the jupyter notebook environment it get step by step no error but if I run it all in a cell it get a error

```
In[2]: fileS = open('my path to file','rb')
       for sheet in wbS.worksheets:
           df = pd.DataFrame(sheet.values)
       df
Out[2]:     0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   ...

      0   None  28S     NaN     NaN     ...     
      1 2017/10/21  850     860.0   870.0   =1600-AVERAGE(BB2:DD2)  
      2 018/08/11   None    NaN     NaN     693     
      3 2018/10/17  925     901.0   923.0   683.667
      4 2018/11/12  959     960.0   966.0   638.333  
      5 2018/12/27  None    NaN     NaN     818.333     
 In[3]: df1 = df.set_index(0)
        df1
 Out[3]:        1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   ...

           0
         NaN    28S     NaN     NaN     ...     
       2017/10/21   850     860.0   870.0   =1600-AVERAGE(BB2:DD2)  
       018/08/11    None    NaN     NaN     693     
       2018/10/17   925     901.0   923.0   683.667
       2018/11/12   959     960.0   966.0   638.333  
  In[4]:rdfS = df1.loc[['2018/08/11','2018/10/17','2018/11/12','2018/12/27'],[4]]
  Out[4]:            4
           0    
       2018/08/11   676.5
       2018/10/17   667.3
       2018/11/12   624.3
       2018/12/27   799
```

By the way the time str is a str I write to the excel file used

```
wb['Sheet1']['A4'] = '2018/10/17'
```

but I run it all in a cell it get error

```
In[1] import openpyxl
      import numpy as np
      import pandas as pd
      fileS = open('my path to file','rb')
      for sheet in wbS.worksheets:
          df = pd.DataFrame(sheet.values)
          df1 = df.set_index(0)
          rdfS = df1.loc[['2018/08/11','2018/10/17','2018/11/12','2018/12/27'],[4]]
 KeyError
         14     df = pd.DataFrame(sheet.values)
         15     df1 = df.set_index(0,drop = True)
--->     16     rdfS = df1.loc[['2018/08/11','2018/10/17','2018/11/12','2018/12/27'],[4]]
      in __getitem__(self, key)
    1365             except (KeyError, IndexError):
    1366                 pass
 -> 1367             return self._getitem_tuple(key)
    1368         else:
    1369             # we by definition only have the 0th axis

     in _getitem_tuple(self, tup)
    861 
    862         # no multi-index, so validate all of the indexers
--> 863         self._has_valid_tuple(tup)
    864 
    865         # ugly hack for GH #836
  in _has_valid_tuple(self, key)
     202             if i >= self.obj.ndim:
     203                 raise IndexingError('Too many indexers')
 --> 204             if not self._has_valid_type(k, i):
     205                 raise ValueError("Location based indexing can         only have "
     206                                  "[{types}] types"
in _has_valid_type(self, key, axis)
     1470                         raise KeyError(
     1471                             u"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis}]".format(
  -> 1472                                 key=key,   axis=self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))
     1473                     else:
     1474 

     KeyError: "None of [['2018/08/11', '2018/10/17', '2018/11/12', '2018/12/27']] are in the [index]"
```

How can I correct it ? Is my environment error or else what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run in jupyter, you are carrying out the operations (`set_index, loc` etc) **only** on the last sheet of the excel sheet (the last sheet in the for loop). when you run the operations on **all** sheet in the new for loop, one of sheet didn't have the dates keys you are trying to `.loc[]`

Comment: But why I'am  part   run in jupyter cell has no error but run it all in a  time has errors.

Comment: I will try to reinstall pandas again

Comment: answer revised to reflect comment

Comment: My every sheet    has  the dates keys I trying to loc[].